# sql 2005 join results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

HI,

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2005:

I have a table "test":

### id, link_id, name

1   11        test1

2   11        test2

3   11        test3

4   12        test4

Is there a way to query this, and return the results grouped by "link_id", with the names joined?

EG,

SELECT link_id, name FROM test WHERE ???????

results:

### link_id,        name(s)

11             test1, test2, test3

12             test4

Comment: In general it is best to let the application do this. It is not a simple or efficient task in the datbase.

Comment: Agreed with HLGEM - better to return all of the items, then loop over them in the application code. However, sometimes this isn't an option - e.g. when working with legacy reporting applications, and so forth, so I can see legitimate uses for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The blackbox way of doing this is with a CROSS APPLY and FOR XML PATH:

```
declare @t table (id int, link_id int, name varchar(max))
insert into @t select 1, 11, 'test1'
union all select 2, 11, 'test2'
union all select 3, 11, 'test3'
union all select 4, 12, 'test4'

select b.link_id, d.link_names
from (
    select distinct link_id
    from @t a
) b
cross apply (
    select name + ', ' as [text()]
    from @t c
    where b.link_id = c.link_id
    for xml path('')
) d (link_names)
```

For each row, a CROSS APPLY executes the applied subquery.  In this case, the subquery is called twice, for link_id 11 and 12.  The subquery then abuses the FOR XML operator to add the strings together.

If you run the query, it will print:

```
11   test1, test2, test3, 
12   test4,
```

Answer (score 2):

A recursive CTE example:

```
declare @t table (id int
                , link_id int
                , [name] varchar(10) )


insert @t
      select 1,11,'test1'
union select 2,11,'test2'
union select 3,11,'test3'
union select 4,12,'test4'

;with rnCTE
AS
(
        select * 
               ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY link_id
                                   ORDER BY  id
                                   ) AS rn
               ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY link_id
                                   ORDER BY  id desc
                                   ) AS rd
        from @t
)
,recCTE
AS
(       select link_id
               ,cast([name] as varchar(max)) as [name]
               ,rn
               ,rd
        from rnCTE
        where rn = 1

        UNION ALL

        select c.link_id
               ,c.[name] + ', ' + t.name as [name]
               ,t.rn
               ,t.rd
        from recCTE c
        join rnCTE  t
        on   t.link_id = c.link_id
        and  t.rn      = c.rn + 1
)
select * from recCTE 
where rd = 1 
order by link_id
```

Comment: Andomar's solution is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article

http://www.sqlprof.com/blogs/sqldev/archive/2008/03/31/how-to-list-multiple-rows-of-data-on-same-line.aspx

Basically you will need to create a function which will return the `test1, test2, test3` part. That is done by setting a variable. Combine that with a distinct list of `link_id`'s and you have got your output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE's (Common Table Expressions) to accomplish this at the database level.  They are a little tricky to work with at first but they can be used to solve some interesting problems.
[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In pure SQL, your best bet would be to write a scalar value function that would group all of your names, like so:

```
DECLARE @Names TABLE (id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, name NVARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @Names SELECT name FROM test WHERE link_id = @link_id

DECLARE @ConcatString NVARCHAR(MAX)

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM @Names)
BEGIN
  SELECT @ConcatString = @ConcatString + ', ' + (SELECT TOP 1 name FROM @Names)
  DELETE FROM @Names WHERE id = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM @Names)
END

RETURN @ConcatString
```

Then you can just do:

```
SELECT link_id, dbo.FunctionName(link_id)
FROM test
GROUP BY link_id
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a function.

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[getname]
```

(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @link_ID as int
)
RETURNS varchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @names as varchar(1000)

```
-- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
SELECT @names = Coalesce(@names + ',', '') + Convert(varchar(1000), name)
from tblTableName
where link_ID = @link_ID

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @names
```

END

then

```
select link_ID, GetName(link_ID) from tblOctHotelImages group by Link_ID, GetName(link_ID)
```

You will get the result.