# Need some help with SQL GroupBY

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a two column table as follows:

```
ID    Emp ID
1      1
1      2
1      3
1      4
2      2
2      6
2      10
3      1
3      5
4      8
5      2
5      6
```

I need something like this:

```
ID   Emp ID
1    1,2,3,4
2    2,6,10
3     1,5
4     8
5     2,6
```

Please help :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715351/sql-2005-join-results

Comment: @Nathan: We don't know the db - the duplicate question is for SQL Server 2005.  But I agree - group concatenated comma separated list questions already exist in SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your database. You need an aggregation function that concatenates the columns and separates them by columns. This, for example, works in sqlite:

```
select
    id,
    group_concat(emp_id)
from
    foo
group by id
```